# How do i turn this tables into an object-oriented table (object-relation) in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have this table below in the picture that i want to create as an object-oriented table. I dont want the usual create table with relationships.... I just want to learn how to turn this table into an object-oriented table. Below is a picture of my tables and how are they connected:

[image: tables]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TYPE A_TYPE AS OBJECT(
  id   INT,
  col1 INT
);
/

CREATE TYPE A_REF_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF REF A_TYPE;
/

CREATE TYPE B_TYPE AS OBJECT(
  id   INT,
  col1 INT
);
/

CREATE TYPE B_REF_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF REF B_TYPE;
/

CREATE TYPE C_TYPE AS OBJECT(
  id     INT,
  a_list A_REF_TABLE_TYPE,
  b_list B_REF_TABLE_TYPE,
  col1   INT
);
/

CREATE TABLE A_TAB OF A_TYPE(
  ID PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE B_TAB OF B_TYPE(
  ID PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE C_TAB OF C_TYPE(
  ID PRIMARY KEY
)
NESTED TABLE a_list STORE AS c_a_lists
NESTED TABLE b_list STORE AS c_b_lists;

INSERT INTO A_TAB VALUES( A_TYPE( 1, 3 ) );
INSERT INTO A_TAB VALUES( 2, 4 );

INSERT INTO B_TAB VALUES ( B_TYPE( 1, 7 ) );
INSERT INTO B_TAB VALUES ( 2, 2 );
INSERT INTO B_TAB VALUES ( 3, 10 );

INSERT INTO C_TAB VALUES (
  1,
  A_REF_TABLE_TYPE(
    ( SELECT REF(a) FROM A_TAB a WHERE ID = 2 ) -- Single value
  ),
  ( -- Multiple values
    SELECT CAST( COLLECT( REF(b) ) AS B_REF_TABLE_TYPE )
    FROM   TAB_B b
    WHERE  ID IN ( 1, 3 )
  ),
  42
);

INSERT INTO C_TAB VALUES (
  2,
  NULL,               -- Unknown
  B_REF_TABLE_TYPE(), -- No values
  54
);
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM C_TAB;

ID A_LIST                          B_LIST                                        COL1
-- ------------------------------- --------------------------------------------- ----
 1 A_REF_TABLE_TYPE( A_TYPE(2,4) ) B_REF_TABLE_TYPE( B_TYPE(1,7), B_TYPE(3,10) )   42
 2 (null)                          B_REF_TABLE_TYPE()                              54
```

Comment: so this would would be it when connecting the three tables to my centered table?

Comment: @EAlexisT This is an example of a single central table `C_TAB` and two others `A_TAB` and `B_TAB` connected to it - you can easily adapt the general principle to your specific use case.